# How to properly recall a function using custom MVC

Tags: php, pdo

Hi and good day to you all..
I'm new to MVC's/model-view-controller frameworks. I've made my own by reverse-engineering a custom MVC framework I've got from a friend of mine, so far it's all going good and smooth until I got to this part where I need to recall a function inside the function it self.. I'm currently creating a binary tree website and need to output values inside the table, what I'm trying to do is call a function and fetch all values and put them inside an array for later referencing.

This is my code in the model folder.

```
public function getGenealogy($parent) {
  $this->db->sql('SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE sponsorUpline = ?');
  $this->db->bindValue(1, $parent);
  $this->db->execute();
  while($row = $this->db->fetch()) {
    echo $row['serialNumber'];
    $this->getGenealogy($row['serialNumber']);
  }
}
```

And this is my code in the controller folder

```
public function index() {
  $memberAccounts = $this->db->getMemberAccounts();
  $getDirectReferal = $this->ddrs->getDirectReferal();
  $genealogy = $this->bg->getGenealogy($_SESSION['activationCode']);
  $data = [
    'memberAccounts' => $memberAccounts,
    'getDirectReferal' => $getDirectReferal,
    'genealogy' => $genealogy
  ];
  $this->view('dashboards/dashboard', $data);
}
```

As you can see, I'm trying to call the function inside of the function but what happens is that it doesn't call it self, I tried doing the same method but not with MVC and it works fine.
So my conclusion is there's something wrong about my code that I can't seem to grasp.

Also it outputs the children twice but with same values.
This is my database.
[image: This is my database]
This is the output.
[image: This is the output].

Any ideas or help would be appreciated.

Comment: it's not a good idea to have a recursive function that uses database and i think your problem is echo in  getGenealogy function . you should return value not to echo it!

Comment: @AliGhalambaz I'm echoing the value for development purposes, I want to see if the function is doing what it is intended to do.